# How to check if sublist exists in list?

Tags: dart

How to check if one list contains another? `.contains` allow only single value.

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  List<int> mylist_1 = [1,3,5,2,7,8];
  List<int> mylist_2 = [1,3,2];
}
```

I need to check if `mylist_1` have `mylist_2`.
Any order of elements in list.

Comment: You mean list or the list elements in exact sequence?

Comment: Is the answer here expected to be true or false? That is, must `mylist_1` contain `[1, 3, 2]` as sub-list (it doesn't, there is a `5` in the way), or must `mylist_1` contain the elements of `[1, 3, 2]` in order? Or in any order?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about checking for duplicates, you can achieve this by converting the first `List` into a `Set` and then calling `containsAll` against the second `List`:

```dart
bool listContainsAll<T>(List<T> a, List<T> b) {
  final setA = Set.of(a);
  return setA.containsAll(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (if duplicate control doesn't matter):

```
import 'package:enumerable/enumerable.dart';

void main() {
  final mylist_1 = [1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8];
  final mylist_2 = [1, 3, 2];

  final contains = mylist_2.except(mylist_1).isEmpty;
  print(contains);
}
```

Result:

```
true
```

More precise check:

```
import 'package:enumerable/enumerable.dart';

void main() {
  final mylist_1 = [1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 2];
  var mylist_2 = [1, 3, 2];
  _check(mylist_1, mylist_2);

  mylist_2 = [1, 3, 2, 2];
  _check(mylist_1, mylist_2);

  mylist_2 = [1, 3, 2, 2, 2];
  _check(mylist_1, mylist_2);
}

void _check<T>(List<T> mylist_1, List<T> mylist_2) {
  final x1 = mylist_1.groupBy((e) => e).toMap((e) => e.key);
  final x2 = mylist_2.groupBy((e) => e);
  final result = x2
          .takeWhile$1((e) => x1[e.key] != null && x1[e.key].length >= e.length)
          .length ==
      x2.length;

  print(mylist_1);
  print(mylist_2);
  print(result);
}
```

Result:

```
[1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 2]
[1, 3, 2]
true
[1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 2]
[1, 3, 2, 2]
true
[1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 2]
[1, 3, 2, 2, 2]
false
```